# Get the latest gitlab pipeline details using python

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to find a way to get the latest pipeline details for a paticular project in gitlab.

I see there is an existing api for it
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines/latest"

but is there any equivalent menthod in python using gitlab python package?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module?

Comment: Yes, I am able to use requests to query the latest pipeline details. But wanted to see if any method in gitlab python module

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.